# SSL error when connecting to git from Mac OS X 10.11.3 (El Capitan)

Tags: macos, git, ssl, curl

When I try to clone / pull / fetch from a git repository via https from a Mac System I keep getting an error:

```
error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

After increasing the log level, I get the following SSL related error:

```
> POST /some/repository.git/git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1
Host: somehost.madeup.now
Authorization: Basic someAuth=
User-Agent: git/2.4.9 (Apple Git-60)
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/x-git-upload-pack-request
Accept: application/x-git-upload-pack-result
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 613

* upload completely sent off: 613 out of 613 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Thu, 10 Mar 2016 09:36:23 GMT
< Server: nginx
< Content-Type: application/x-git-upload-pack-result
< Status: 200 OK
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< X-Request-Id: 531bdbc2-cc8d-407b-961a-f8b7dcd45baf
< X-Runtime: 0.138041
< Connection: close
< 
* SSLRead() return error -9806
```

I found a very similar case on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30385939/git-clone-fails-with-sslread-error-on-os-x-yosemite), and I followed the steps in the accepted answer, which means upgrading git, curl and openssl with homebrew to the newest versions:

```
git: 2.7.2
curl: 7.47.1
openssl: 1.0.2g
```

In my case this didn't help. I keep getting the same errors.

Any ideas what could be the reason for this failure?

Comment: Are your Mac's and git server's system clocks close?

Comment: Searching Google reveals other OSX users reporting similar issues with certain versions of curl on Yosemite. For some a reboot fixes it. Others require reinstalling curl https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/819#issuecomment-55165813

Comment: @spuder they are about 15 seconds apart

Comment: @spuder neither reboot nor reinstall helped